# Changing data before exporting excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have a list which contains boolean values. I want to export that list to excel, but it must be meaningful for the customer. When I export it as it is, it shows values like `True` and `False` as expected, but these values might probably have no meaning in the perception of the customer. This is the way I do the excel export:

```
LiveModReports model = new LiveModReports();
        List<ModerationDM.DetailedContent> liveModListDM = new List<ModerationDM.DetailedContent>();

        liveModListDM = contentBLL.GetContentsForMod(modId, startDate, endDate);

        if (liveModListDM != null)
        {
            model.ContentExcelList = new List<ContentExcel>();

            foreach (var item in liveModListDM)
            {
                model.ContentExcelList.Add(new ContentExcel()
                {                        
                    ModerasyonNumarasi = item.ModId,
                    Kategori = item.Category,
                    AltKategori = item.SubCategory,
                    IcerikAdresi = item.ContentURL,
                    IcerikSahibiTamAdi = item.ContentUFullName,
                    IcerikSahibiEPosta = item.ContentUserEmail,
                    IcerikMetni = item.ContentText,
                    Durumu = item.ResultCode,
                    SonDegistirilmeTarihi = (DateTime)item.ModifiedTime,
                    ModerasyonKategorisi = item.ModCategoryName,
                    IcerikNumarasi = item.ContentSeqNum,
                    BegeniPuani = item.LikeCount,
                    BegenilmemePuani = item.DislikeCount,
                    PaneldenVerilmisCevapMi = item.IsAnswer,
                    CevaplanmisMi = item.IsAnswered,
                    RaporlamaBasligi = item.ReportHeader
                });
            }


        }
        CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(model.ContentExcelList, "IcerikListesi.xlsx", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response);
```

For example, IsAnswer must be shown as "Evet" which means "Yes" in Turkish, but it's shown as "True" now. How can I change the values before they're written to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ternary operator in order to be more meaningful with your data, for example:

```
PaneldenVerilmisCevapMi = (item.IsAnswer ? "Yes" : "No"),
...
```

Explain: if `IsAnswers` evaluates to `true`, use "Yes", otherwise, use "No".

Note that `PaneldenVerilmisCevapMi` must be a `string`.

**UPDATE:**

if `item.IsAnswer` is a nullable type, change your if statement to:

```
PaneldenVerilmisCevapMi = (item.IsAnswer.HasValue ? "Yes" : "No"),
```

Comment: No need for those brackets.

Comment: IsAnswer is nullable and it leads an error, how can I check nullables if they are true/false?

Answer (score 2):

You are the one preparing the model **before** writing it to Excel. Thus, you can simply change the properties to fit your needs.

Examples like

```
PaneldenVerilmisCevapMi = (item.IsAnswer) ? "Evet" : "No"
```

would work for you but you can do anything with these objects. Such as - passing it to a method that changes things like `True` to `Evet` or anything else that will look beter for an end user.

```
MakeDataReadable(model.ContentExcelList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write this:

```
PaneldenVerilmisCevapMi = (item.IsAnswer) ? "Evet" : "No"
```